# C++ Dynamic memory allocation in template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class and template

```
class MyClass{
public:
    int data;
};

template< typename Tp> Tp makeObj()
{
    /// How is this allocated
    Tp obj;
    obj->data = 10;
    return obj;
}
```

And a main function

```
int main()
{    
    /// Remove the next line and "makeObj" will return a null ptr
    /// I have no idea why    
    std::vector<int> vec;
    MyClass *tmp = makeObj<MyClass*>();
    std::cout << tmp->data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n\n | DONE3 -> " << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The "makeObj" function returns a null ptr, but when I add "std::vector" line, it returns a valid ptr, then I remove it again, it returns a null ptr.

My question is how is that ptr allocated? and is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take the template function you have

```
template< typename Tp> Tp makeObj()
{
    /// How is this allocated
    Tp obj;
    obj->data = 10;
    return obj;
}
```

and expand it with the type

```
MyClass* makeObj()
{
    /// How is this allocated
    MyClass* obj;
    obj->data = 10;
    return obj;
}
```

Now you can clearly see that you don't actually allocate a `MyClass` object, only a *pointer* to it. This pointer will be uninitialized and dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

One possible solution is to not have a template argument being a pointer, but the type, then explicitly use a pointer to it in the function template:

```
// Declare the return-type to be a pointer
//                       v
template< typename Tp> Tp* makeObj()
{
    /// How is this allocated
    Tp* obj = new Tp;  // Declare variable as a pointer,
                       // and actually create an instance of the type
    obj->data = 10;
    return obj;
}
```

Use it as

```
// Explicitly declares as a pointer
//      v
MyClass *tmp = makeObj<MyClass>();
//                     ^^^^^^^
// And pass the plain class-type as the template argument, not a pointer
```

Comment: Yes, now I use templates as you proposed, I came to the previous code by accident ( the one in question), but why do I still get a valid pointer, that outputs "10"?

Comment: @AsItis Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Just because the code compiles and *seems* to work doesn't mean it's correct. A decent compiler (possible with flags or options to enable more warnings) would tell you about the uninitialized variable use in `makeObj`.

Comment: Well, the compiler returned these warnings
warning: variable 'obj' is uninitialized when used here
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'makeObj<MyClass *>' requested here
note: initialize the variable 'obj' to silence this warning

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning a valid pointer, instead it is returning whatever happens to be on the stack. The contents of the stack inside make-_obj are changed by the inclusion of the "std::vector vec;" line.

What you have is pure undefined behavior.

Comment: This code was buried in a larger code ,it compiled and worked as expected, I was headed for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple: the way you use it, `Tp` is treated as a value. It doesn't matter that it may be a pointer, since pointers are values. You could think of a pointer as `intptr_t` with some extras added. So, `makeObj` makes an instance of *the pointer*. But this pointer doesn't point to anything. So, `obj->data = 10` is undefined behavior. And from this point onwards, your code can be doing anything. That's where the analysis ends. You need to fix `makeObj`. I presume that `makeObj` is supposed to be a factory function.

Below is an example of how `makeObj` could look. You really don't want to be messing about with raw pointers. Factory functions should return `std::unique_ptr` or an equivalent (e.g. `kj::Own` from [capnproto](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/tree/master/c%2B%2B/src/kj)). That's how idiomatic modern C++ should look.

You also don't need to use console i/o to confirm that things work as expected: you can `assert`, and the debugger will stop at the point where the assertion fails. There's a small step from that to test-driven development; you'd use a variant of "assert" that's specific to the test framework you're using. But even without a test framework, it's easy to check things using assert when you're playing with stuff.

Given that we live in the wonderful times where you can access a C++ compiler and debugger in the browser, you can experiment with the code below at https://onlinegdb.com/BJZOB6gKH

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

template <class T, class... Args> std::unique_ptr<T> makeObj(Args &&... args) {
  auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  ptr->data = 10;
  return ptr;
}

struct MyType { 
    int foo = {};
    int data = {};
    MyType() = default;
    MyType(int foo, int data) : foo(foo), data(data) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto t = makeObj<MyType>(5, 20);
    assert(t->foo == 5);
    assert(t->data == 10);
    auto u = makeObj<MyType>();
    assert(u->foo == 0);
    assert(u->data == 10);
}
```